# Resource file max entry length c#

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, resx

I have a resource file which holds all the upgrade scripts which run differentially when the application starts. Over time a lot of scripts have gone into the resource file. Today I put a new script in which is very big (73000 characters).

When the application is started the application will try get this script from resource file but it is returning an empty string. Is there a limit to a resource file entry? I would have thought it wouldn't after all its just another class right? Any other helpful ideas why this returns an empty string would be helpful - possibly invalid characters or something?

EDIT: I had barely click Ask Question when it occurred to me that the script has HTML tags in it. So I guess the real question is - is it even possible to store this in the resource file?

Here is a small snippet from the script -

```
INSERT [dbo].[t_ST_SmartFormVersion] ([SmartFormId], [Version], [Description], [IsActive], [CategoryId], [EditHtml], [ViewHtml], [CreatedBy], [CreatedDate], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Fields]) VALUES (@Id1, N'1.1', N'Trained First Aiders Register', 1, NULL, N'<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset"><li><h1 style="text-align: center;">Trained First Aiders Register</h1></li></ul>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that gets the script and any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to store HTML in the resource file. You need to double check the properties of the file (make sure you've got it set to Resource') and check the retrieval code - make sure the resource exists with the given key and your code is not obscuring the fact that a resource is missing or key is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Never found an elegant solution. Had to literally escape the entire 73000 character string using a small app I wrote specifically for this. The testing team is going to love me when I tell them they will have to check it all.